# how to put line break in c# for report view

Tags: c#

How to put line break between two lines?

I tried to put `Enviroment.NewLine();` but it not worked

```
private void AddHeader(int pageNo)
{
    if (pageNo>0)
    {
        AddText("Date", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 100, 130, pageNo);
        AddText("Time", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 320, 130, pageNo);
        AddText("Value", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 500, 130, pageNo);
    }
    else
    {
        AddText("Tank No:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 103, 125, pageNo);
        AddText("Date:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 105, 150, pageNo);
        AddText("Time:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 103, 175, pageNo);
        AddText("From:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 165, 175, pageNo);
        AddText("To:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 165, 200, pageNo);
        AddText("Time duration:", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 105, 225, pageNo);
        AddText("Date", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 105, 250, pageNo);
        AddText("Time", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 325, 250, pageNo);
        AddText("Value", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 516, 250, pageNo);
    }
}
```

I need to include line break between "Timed duration" and "Date", which are above the "Time duration" are just text which will get the data, but the below part "date" "time" "value" are a table.

Comment: please also let us know which platform that you want to show? web? winform? or construct in PDF?

Comment: windows plat form

Comment: Do you mean a new line or actually drawing a line across the page?

Comment: And where is the `AddText` method defined?

Comment: AddText is used represent the Words which will appear in Listview, i want to add linebreak between two lines of data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried good old "\n" character?

```
 AddText("Date", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 100, 130, pageNo);

 AddText("\n", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 100, 130, pageNo);

 AddText("Time", "Arial", 14, true, 0, Colors.Black, 320, 130, pageNo);
```